# KDB+ Q Unit test Analytics Code in Delta Control

Tags: unit-testing, kdb

Im new Q language and i want to  unit test the Analytics code (q code). I'm using the Delta Control ide for development. In KX documents i came across the [K4unit](https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/unit-tests/) and i would like to use this. i have few questions here

1. How do i load the k4unit code inside Analytics Library in the Delta Control Ide.
2. I would like to create a framework for unit test , so that i would be used across.

Any lights or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also check https://github.com/nugend/qspec testing framework. It has some good features like test descriptions, mocking. Although I am not sure whether it is actively maintained.

Comment: thanks for the response yeah i checked this before. now problem is i dont see a way to use the K4 unit library in the Delta Control but if its in the Q developer i had unit tested the POC code and it was great .

Comment: Hi PremJKumar, If you are using DeltaControl you likely have access to the qCumber testing suite. Have you looked into that?

Comment: Thanks i did checked qCumber and QuickCheq but i couldn't find the namespace package deployed and since i'm new couldnt find a way that it is being available or not as part of my Delta control. i tried to execute the .qch.g.reify .qch.g.dict[] it throws me an in error in the ide. Let me know if there is way to figure this out.

Comment: @PremKumarR DeltaControl is an officially licensed product from First Derivatives/Kx - you should thus have access to their direct support channel and I think that would be a better place to ask. Most people here in stack overflow are likely not using that product.

Comment: @terrylynch Thanks for the response . will check with them